# Log Analytics Search Results in ADF

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to manipulate Log Analytics Query Results and hitting a road block...not really sure where to ask, so please point me in the correct direction if this is not it. I've been banging my head against the wall for about a week on this one. I figured out how to do this via a series of web activities and 3 nested pipelines, but Web Activities dont support the data volume the copy activity does.

The REST API for Log Analytics output is of the form:

```
{
"tables": [
    { 
         "name": "PrimaryResult",
         "columns": [
                         { "name": "Category", "type": "string" }, 
                         { "name": "count_", "type": "long" }
                    ],
          "rows": [
                     [ "Administrative", 20839 ],
                     [ "ServiceHealth", 11 ]
           ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to create a JSON object of the form

`[{"Category":"Administrative", "count_": 20839},{"Category":"ServiceHealth", "count_": 11}]`

Any ideas? Again, if this is the wrong forum, please let me know and I will adjust accordingly.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge,there is no built-in feature in ADF could process the result for you.

```
[{"Category":"Administrative", "count_": 20839},{"Category":"ServiceHealth", "count_": 11}]
```

You have to manipulate the result by yourself.I suggest you creating a [HTTP Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) to implement this which is supported by ADF Azure Function Activity. Just set it up after Web Activity mentioned in your quesiton.

I wrote test sample for you in Python code. Certainly, you could use any language you know.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    req_body = req.get_json()

    tables = req_body["tables"]
    returnArray = []
    for table in tables: 
        for row in table["rows"]:
            info ={}
            for inx,value in enumerate(row):
                info[table["columns"][inx]["name"]] = value
            returnArray.append(info)   

    if req_body:
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(returnArray ))
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Test Output:

[image]